# jquery datepicker is not displaying yearRange

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use jQuery datepicker and need one with the years select element. This is the code of my element:

```
$("#geburtsdatum").datepicker({
    "yearRange":"2000:2010",
    "firstDay":1,
    "dayNamesMin":["So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa"],
    "monthNames":["Januar","Februar","M&auml;rz","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"],
    "dateFormat":"dd.mm.yy"});
```

However I am missing the select in my datepicker. Has anybody any idea what am I doing wrong? (I'm working with jquery-1.7.1.)

[image: my datepicker]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "changeYear" option. [See the source on the documentations page here.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year)

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like

```
$("#geburtsdatum").datepicker({
yearRange: "2000:2010",
firstDay: 1,
dayNamesMin: ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "M&auml;rz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
changeYear: true
});​
```

Here's a working fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/WByxq/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
$(".datefield").datepicker({
    minDate: (new Date(1920, 0, 1)),
    maxDate: "+100Y",
    yearRange: '1920:2020',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function() { $(this).valid(); }
});
```